# Problem with last record in ms access query

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 Access queries , The **first query (Q0)** filters a table to get specific data :

[image: The Table Data]

```
    SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Machine, Table1.Po, Table1.Priority, Table1.Zdate, Table1.Status
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Status)<>"Not Needed"));
```

The **second query (Q1)** Sorts the first query depending on multiple condition like date and priority :

```
    SELECT Q0.Machine, Q0.Priority, Q0.Zdate, Q0.Po, Q0.ID, Q0.Status
FROM Q0
GROUP BY Q0.Machine, Q0.Priority, Q0.Zdate, Q0.Po, Q0.ID, Q0.Status
ORDER BY Q0.Machine, Q0.Priority DESC , Q0.Zdate;
```

[image: Q1 Data]

The **third query (Q2)** :

```
 SELECT Table2.MachineNumber, Last(Q1.Priority) AS LastOfPriority, Last(Q1.Zdate) AS LastOfZdate, Last(Q1.Po) AS LastOfPo, Last(Q1.ID) AS LastOfID, Last(Q1.Status) AS LastOfStatus
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Q1 ON Table2.MachineNumber = Q1.Machine
GROUP BY Table2.MachineNumber;
```

[image: Q2]

Q2 should get the last record for each machine number in the Q1 with the rest of data in the same record , So the priority should be all "1" with the right date , the right Po and the right status  , Unfortunately it doesn’t happen and get the record with the last ID in each machine number .

The correct result should be like

[image: Correct Result]

Sorry For long question guys , Thanks in advance

Edit#1
I just need the last record from each machine number in Q1 no matter what condition because it is not always the latest date or the highest priority i need the Q2 to Strictly tied to the last record of each machine number
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Last` but `Max`:

```
SELECT Table2.MachineNumber, Max(Q1.Priority) AS HighPriority, Max(Q1.Zdate) As LatestDate, ... etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , About that it is not always the latest date it could be the first or the one before last etc.. and the same goes with priority .. I just need the last record for every machine number from Q1 .. Just like the image in Edit #1

Comment: Then you must sort by the ID.

Comment: No other way ? By adding new query maybe ? i also could try appending the result to a temp table and make new query on that table .. Thanks any way

Comment: A "last record" must be defined by sort on one or more fields. If that is not possible, use a spreadsheet.